# JQuery Datepicker calender control popup not opening second time only in Firefox

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-datepicker

This issue is replicated only in Firefox (IE and Chrome are working a expected). Initially when page loads, if we click on the datepicker textbox, calendar control opens. Now if user tries to click outside of calendar control, calendar control pop-up closes. Now try to click on datepicker textbox again. Calendar pop-up does not show up. Calendar control (ui-datepicker-div) "display" attribute is getting set to none only in Firefox.

[Fiddler Sample Url](http://jsfiddle.net/03saafry/)

Can anyone please help me to solve this issue?

**HTML:**

```
<input type="text" id="maturitydatepicker"/>
```

**JS:**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#maturitydatepicker").datepicker({
        showOn: 'both',
        dateFormat: 'dd-MM-yy',       
        buttonImageOnly: true,
        showButtonPanel: true,
        changeMonth: true,
        changeYear: true,
        closeText: 'clear',
        buttonText: 'Select Date',
        onClose: function (dateText, inst) {

            if ($(window.event.srcElement).hasClass('ui-datepicker-close')) {              
                document.getElementById(this.id).value = '';
            }
        },
        onChangeMonthYear: function (y, m, i) {
            var d = i.selectedDay;
            $(this).datepicker('setDate', new Date(y, m - 1, OnMonthYearChangeDateCheck(d, m - 1, y)));           
        }       
    });
});
```

Comment: with limited information provided, this code is causing the issue, `            if ($(window.event.srcElement).hasClass('ui-datepicker-close')){              
                document.getElementById(this.id).value = '';
            }` removing it solve the problem

Comment: Thanks Shehary for pointing me to the problematic code. I updated my question with workable solution.

Comment: No problem, you are welcome

Answer (score 0):

You should add parameter to function like this

```
$(document).ready(function (e)
```

and declare a variable like this :

```
 var evt = e || window.event 
if ($(evt.srcElement).hasClass('ui-datepicker-close'))
```

Because FF doesn't have window.event so you have to declare an other

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion but the above code changes did not work for me. "If" block never resulted in true when user clicks on Close button.

Answer (score 0):

Below code block solved my issue in all browsers.

```
 onClose: function () {
                var event = arguments.callee.caller.caller.arguments[0];
                // If "Clear" gets clicked, then really clear it
                if ($(event.delegateTarget).hasClass('ui-datepicker-close')) {
                    $(this).val('');
                }
            }
```